# When did households become electrified?

Tags: 20th-century, technology, electricity

The first households were supplied with electricity in the 1880s (from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_power_industry)). I think by around 1950 most urban households in the US had electricity. Rural households got there a few years later? The situation in Western Europe was similar? How electrified was Germany before and after world war II? Essentially I'm looking for charts showing the proportion of households with electric power over time for various regions in the world and my googling didn't provide anything useful beyond the wikipedia article.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Europe the situation, for most countries, was different.

Gas and Electricity development was something that was developed on a local level.

---

### Berlin, Germany

For street lighting, Electricity replaced Gas rather swiftly after 1884.

1895 steetcars were electrified and after 1902 the underground system being build also used electricity.

For households, starting around 1890, gas was primarily used for ovens as a replacement for coal or wood. Even in the 1930's, electric ovens were still unpopular.

| Year | Households with electricity in % |
| --- | --- |
| 1910 | 3.5% |
| 1914 | 5% |
| 1925 | 25% |
| 1929 | 50% |

Until the 1930's, households used electricity primarily for lighting.

In 1928 only 3,5% used it for cooking appliances, 0.5% for washing machines and 0.2% for refrigerators.

---

**Sources**:

- [Die Elektrifizierung Deutschlands – Deutsches Historisches Museum: Blog](https://www.dhm.de/blog/2016/08/25/die-elektrifizierung-deutschlands/)
- [Die Anfänge der Elektrizitätsversorgung - Berlin unter Strom | Berliner Mieterverein e.V.](https://www.berliner-mieterverein.de/magazin/online/mm1114/111424.htm)
- [Gas- und Stromgeschichte - Berlin EnergieBerlin Energie](https://www.berlinenergie.de/konzessionsverfahren/gas-und-stromgeschichte/)
- [Geschichte der Berliner Energieversorgung - Vattenfall](https://group.vattenfall.com/de/newsroom/blog/2019/mai/geschichte-berliner-energieversorgung)

Comment: Gas ovens are even now pretty common in Germany. In the UK, they are apparently even common in high-rise appartement blocks, but in Germany they seem to be confined to smaller houses. Gas ovens have a number of advantages over simple electrical stoves, e.g. more power and easier to regulate output. So IMHO mentioning gas here is a bit meaningless.

Comment: Is your table for % households that use electricity for cooking (in that case it is contradicted by numbers given in text below) or for % households that use electricity at all (in that case the preceding sentence gives the impression the table is about cooking)

Comment: And might be worth mentioning that coal/wood was also quite common for cooking.

Comment: @Jan (This may be Berlin specific) A major cause for the low amount of connected households was due to the existing gas network (since the late 1840's) and the higher price for electricity. So the role of gas seems to me relevant. Text and column header has been adapted.

Comment: In the United States, it is common even today in new homes to have an electric oven but a gas stove.  I would guess this is because it's faster to get a large pot boiling on a gas stove, especially if one of the burners is specifically designed for this purpose.

Comment: @C Monsour: It's more that gas stoves are far more responsive when you want temperature changes.  Electric stoves are slow to heat up and cool down.   See the Cooking site for details.

Comment: @CMonsour In Berlin gas ovens are still quite common. Unfortunately in rented flats either it (or the building) has a gas connection or not. My present flat doesn't and I miss it sorly.

Comment: @MarkJohnson, that's a different gas. Today we use natural gas. Back in the day it was "Rauchgas" - coal was heated in the absence of air and the resulting gas was filtered and collected in huge tanks. It was then used in street lighting and in households that could afford it. But the gas burnt very dirtily, and no modern gas oven would survive being run on Rauchgas, so saying "Berlin still uses gas ovens" suggests a continuity where none exists.

Comment: @EikePierstorff Most peaple don't make that distinction, they use whaever the [GASAG](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/GASAG) (founded 1843) sends through the pipes. In western Berlin the switch between *Stadtgas* (Rauchgas) and *Erdgas* started in 1985 and was compleated in 1991. Any needed replacement oven/heaters were done during that period. [Wenn neues Gas durch alte Rohre strömt - taz.de](https://taz.de/!1498107/)

Comment: @MarkJohnson there one thinks one is smart, and then learns something new. I used to live near the Schöneberg Gasworks and took occasionally part in tours around there, but it seems not everything I learned was accurate.

Comment: @EikePierstorff If I remember correctly, it was only a matter of exchanging the gas nozzels (to support the higher pressure). Then you had to wait a few days until the neighbourhood was switched over.

Answer (score 2):

Just a data point, but according to [this German wp article](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elektrifizierung), only 11 percent of US farms had electricity in 1934, while the share of farms with electricity in Germany and France was around 90 percent at the same time.